# Programmatic cutting on a ZPL printer from c#

Tags: c#, printing, zpl

I am developing a program in C# to process shipping requests with UPS, register them in the clients database and send the new labels to a networked ZPL printer.

We are working with a GX420T Zebra printer with a cutter.  Printing labels works without issue via IP.

I am having an issue cutting the labels.  The client wants each shipment's labels to be connected, but separated from the labels of other shipments. (ie. only cut after all the shipment's labels are printed)  With a shipment of a single label the label is cut as expected.  With shipments of multiple labels the cutter never runs.

```
        bool print = true; //true: If printing fails on the first label,
                           // do not try the rest.
                           //false: do not print

        //Set printer mode
        print = parseZPL.printZPL_IP(@"^XA^MMD^XZ");

        //Save and print Package labels
        foreach (XElement package in Packages)
        {   //Parse XML
            if (package.Name.LocalName == "PackageResults")
            {
                //Pulling Package and Shipping label information from XML
                string ShippingLabel = package.Element(ship + "ShippingLabel").Element(ship + "GraphicImage").Value;

                //convert string to Base64
                byte[] ZPLbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ShippingLabel);

                if (print)
                {
                    print = parseZPL.printZPL_IP(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ZPLbytes));
                }
            }
        };

        if (print)
        {
            print = parseZPL.printZPL_IP(@"~JK");
        }
```

I tried adding a sleep() command before the ~JK command, with no success.  I have scoured the ZPL Documentation without finding a solution that worked.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: As far as I remember, ^MMC command is for cut.

Comment: @liquide, I believe you are correct, however, it cuts after each label, and my client wants to cut only after all the labels in a specific shipment are printed.  I will try to update my questions to be more clear on that.

Comment: Is there anything different in your multi-shipment-label vs a single-shipment label? Reset of Printer Mode for example? Or is the output of printZPL_IP() for the second label false? (so ~JK might be skipped because print == false)

Comment: @Johan, I will double check that `print` isn't set to `false`, but the labels print without issue.  The only difference between single- and multiple-shipment labels is how many times the initial `if` statement in the `foreach` loop comes back `true`.

As a side note, all of the labels are successfully saved individually as files as well - removed for code brevity - which is another reason I don't think it's a loop issue.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am having the same problem, and it's related to the printer expecting ~JK to be sent separately. I am sending it through a separate stream.

Comment: I've played around with it a bit more and I think my problem at least is due to the fact the label ZPL is being streamed to the printer rather than queued as a print job/file. Because of this sending the ~JK command doesn't get picked up as an individual job as required by Zebra. It just goes immediately into the stream. You have to wait for the printer to return to idle before it works. So the solution is finding the correct approach to queueing up the ~JK command to printer so it prints when the labels have finished.

Comment: @JosephKreifelsII For me, this was 7 years ago, and I can not find where I saved the code.  However, I believe that I used the accepted answer.  Using `^MMT` for the first (or all the labels) and `^MMC` on the last, instead of setting the same mode for all of the labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When printing a batch of labels, I think you need to set `^MMT` (tearoff) at the start of the first label, and `^MMC` (cut) at the start of the last label.

Comment: Good idea, I'm testing it right now.  It seems like **TearOff** might be a good name for physical users, but on the programming side, **DoNothing** might be more descriptive.  (If I'm understanding this correctly)

Comment: @Abe Tear-Off is one of the many print modes on the printer, and probably the most standard one. In Tear-Off mode the printer will print the label into tear-off position. You can see the difference by printing with MMD for example. In Delayed Cut mode the last label will be a bit forwards. So if you were to try and tear it off at this point, you're likely to tear the next one by accident. So TearOff is in fact doing something.